How to Dynamically Update Graphs (Add/Remove Edges) in cuGraph with C++?
I am currently working with NVIDIA's cuGraph library to perform graph analytics in a C++ environment. My application requires the ability to dynamically update graphs by adding or removing edges and then reconstructing the graph for further analysis. I am specifically using the Compressed Sparse Row (CSR) format to represent graphs.
Despite searching through the cuGraph documentation and various resources, I have not found a clear way to efficiently manage dynamic graphs, especially with regards to:

Dynamically adding edges to an existing graph.
Dynamically removing edges from an existing graph.
Efficiently reconstructing or updating the graph's CSR representation after such modifications.

My current approach involves manipulating the CSR arrays directly, but this seems inefficient and cumbersome, particularly for large-scale graphs or frequent updates.
I am looking for guidance or best practices on managing dynamic graphs in cuGraph with C++. Specifically, I am interested in any existing functionalities within cuGraph or recommended strategies to handle graph updates without needing to reconstruct the graph from scratch each time.

Does cuGraph offer built-in support for dynamically adding or removing edges in a graph, and if so, how can this be done in C++?


Updating a CSR representation is generally quite expensive and inefficient. Therefore one rather wants to start with a maximal graph and then mask parts that are unneeded at any point. cuGraph seems to work on these kinds of features, see this GitHub epic.

Much to unpack here.  I'll answer your questions in order.
Support for Dynamic Graphs
cuGraph was originally designed to perform static graph analysis.  The objective was to optimize the creation of a CSR-like structure and then use that CSR-like structure to run graph algorithms.  While we were aware during the initial design period of use cases for dynamic graphs, our expectation was that for many use cases just recreating the CSR-like structure with the new data would be "fast enough".
In the current software (prior and through release 24.04 which should come out later this month), the only real option you have for inserting edges is to keep the original COO (or reconstruct it), add the edges to the COO, destroy the cugraph::graph_t object and create a new cugraph::graph_t from the new COO.
We have slowly been adding a masking feature to mask out edges, should be fully supported in release 24.04.  I don't have a good example to point you to, that's still on our list of things to do.  It should resemble something like this: https://github.com/rapidsai/cugraph/blob/f753e5146bac7243d962736a9377a843ca81fd6f/cpp/tests/prims/mg_count_if_e.cu#L110.  If you post a question on our GitHub we can probably walk you through the development process for simulating the removal of edges by masking them out.
We have started working on updates to cuGraph to add the ability to support dynamic graphs, although we don't have an exact timeline on that support.  I would expect to have a timeline over the next few months, you can probably search our GitHub over the next few months to find that timeline.
Updating a CSR
There isn't really a good way to update a CSR.  I suspect our dynamic graph implementation will leverage the research done in hornet and STINGer, but we haven't finalized the implementation yet.
Performance Considerations for Dynamic Graphs
I think this is moot given the current lack of support.  We are intending for our solution to have good performance, and there will be strategies for using it that will have better performance (in our design meetings we have started outlining different use cases that will drive our optimization approach).  But it is premature to describe them since the design is not even finalized, let alone built.
Support for DFS
There is no natural way to support DFS in cuGraph.  The GPU gets good performance by doing many things in parallel.  DFS, by its nature, is a serial process as you select only one edge to traverse at each decision point.
Part of the reason that DFS is so widely used in serial code is that it limits the requirement for extra memory while you are traversing the graph, so you end up with a high performing serial code with little extra memory requirement.  BFS, in contrast, requires extra memory to manage the current frontier (potentially as large as O(E)), and you need to inherently think about the order in which you visit things and perhaps have ancillary data structures to keep track of work that has already be done.  However, BFS is naturally friendly to parallelism, so the extra bookkeeping has a big payoff when running in parallel - especially on the GPU.
Generally when we encounter an algorithm that is implemented using DFS, we do one of the following:

Search for another implementation that uses BFS.  DFS is great for serial implementations, but all parallel implements struggle with DFS. This is amplified on the GPU because of the massive parallelism.  Many serial DFS-based algorithms have parallel BFS-based equivalents, and if you can find one that's an easier starting point.
Devise another approach that uses BFS.  Certainly not all algorithms based on DFS have been explored by the research community to define a good parallel implementation.  You can frequently find a good analog that would be a good starting point.
Find a way to run many DFS instances concurrently (more below).

The latter method can be seen in our sampling software.  Our sampling algorithm does a random sample of the neighborhood of a vertex.  While it is technically still a breadth-first approach (since we create a new frontier with the sampled neighbors in it), it is bounded by the sample size, which makes it resemble a depth-first approach from a performance perspective.  We never get enough parallelism on a single seed in order to get efficient usage of the GPU.
To address that we create a batch of seeds and run sampling on all seeds at once.  If the batch of seeds is large enough, we can completely saturate the computation capacity of the GPU and get significant performance acceleration.
So, if you must use DFS, you would need to be able to do many DFS computations in parallel on each GPU.  The exact number required to get good performance on the GPU would be dependent on many things... what your code is doing in addition to traversing depth-first, what model GPU you are using, whether your data fits on one GPU or you need to spread it across multiple GPUs.  You probably need to have tens to hundreds of thousands of concurrent DFS computations to saturate the GPU.  This is a frequent area where we configure things so we can tune performance for each problem/GPU configuration.
I definitely would recommend posting one or more questions on our GitHub: https://github.com/rapidsai/cugraph/issues.  We'd be happy to hear more details about your dynamic graph requirements and algorithm requirements.  We have a variety of algorithms on our upcoming roadmap and we're always happy to add things to the roadmap, discuss things with users of our software and otherwise collaborate.
